# Brunch Not Compiling CSS For VueJS Components in Phoenix 1.3 Project?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch

I’m having trouble getting Brunch to build VueJS components after moving to Phoenix 1.3.

I’ve generated a new project.

I’ve installed vue-brunch integration using NPM:
(Found here: https://github.com/nblackburn/vue-brunch.git”

I’ve updated the brunch-config.js to build Vue components like so (I tried both paths to components.css):

```
  // Configure your plugins
  plugins: {
    babel: {
      // Do not use ES6 compiler in vendor code
      ignore: [/vendor/]
    },
    vue: {
      extractCSS: true,
      out: 'priv/static/css/components.css'
      // out: '../priv/static/css/components.css'
    }
  },
```

I’ve added a component to “assets/components/my-app.vue”.

But after building the project “components.css” does not show up in, “priv/static/css/”.

I’ve tried updating Brunch.  No luck.

What did I miss?

For more context, the full brunch-config.js file:

```
exports.config = {
  // See http://brunch.io/#documentation for docs.
  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"

      // To use a separate vendor.js bundle, specify two files path
      // http://brunch.io/docs/config#-files-
      // joinTo: {
      //   "js/app.js": /^js/,
      //   "js/vendor.js": /^(?!js)/
      // }
      //
      // To change the order of concatenation of files, explicitly mention here
      // order: {
      //   before: [
      //     "vendor/js/jquery-2.1.1.js",
      //     "vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      //   ]
      // }
    },
    stylesheets: {
      joinTo: "css/app.css"
    },
    templates: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"
    }
  },

  conventions: {
    // This option sets where we should place non-css and non-js assets in.
    // By default, we set this to "/assets/static". Files in this directory
    // will be copied to `paths.public`, which is "priv/static" by default.
    assets: /^(static)/
  },

  // Phoenix paths configuration
  paths: {
    // Dependencies and current project directories to watch
    watched: ["static", "css", "js", "vendor"],
    // Where to compile files to
    public: "../priv/static"
  },

  // Configure your plugins
  plugins: {
    babel: {
      // Do not use ES6 compiler in vendor code
      ignore: [/vendor/]
    },
    vue: {
      extractCSS: true,
      out: 'priv/static/css/components.css'
    }
  },

  modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      "js/app.js": ["js/app"]
    }
  },

  npm: {
    enabled: true
  }
};
```

**brunch build --debug output**

> $ brunch build --debug
>
> brunch:config Trying to load brunch-config +0ms   brunch:plugins
>   Loaded plugins: babel-brunch +690ms   brunch:watch add package.json
>   +28ms   brunch:watch add brunch-config.js +0ms   brunch:watch add static/favicon.ico +5ms   brunch:list Reading static/favicon.ico +1ms 
>   brunch:watch add static/robots.txt +0ms   brunch:list Reading
>   static/robots.txt +0ms   brunch:watch add css/app.css +1ms
>   brunch:list Reading css/app.css +0ms   brunch:watch add
>   css/phoenix.css +1ms   brunch:list Reading css/phoenix.css +0ms
>   brunch:watch add js/app.js +0ms   brunch:list Reading js/app.js +0ms
>   brunch:watch add js/socket.js +0ms   brunch:list Reading js/socket.js
>   +0ms   brunch:asset Init asset static/favicon.ico +3ms   brunch:list Compiled static/favicon.ico +4ms   brunch:asset Init asset
>   static/robots.txt +0ms   brunch:list Compiled static/robots.txt +0ms
>   brunch:file Init file css/app.css +1ms   brunch:list Compiled
>   css/app.css +3ms   brunch:file Init file js/app.js +0ms
>   brunch:pipeline Compiling js/app.js @ babel-brunch +1ms   brunch:file
>   Init file js/socket.js +254ms   brunch:pipeline Compiling js/socket.js
>   @ babel-brunch +0ms   brunch:file Init file css/phoenix.css +55ms
>   brunch:list Compiled css/phoenix.css +1ms   brunch:watch add
>   static/images/phoenix.png +3ms   brunch:list Reading
>   static/images/phoenix.png +0ms   brunch:asset Init asset
>   static/images/phoenix.png +8ms   brunch:list Compiled
>   static/images/phoenix.png +0ms   brunch:list Reading
>   node_modules/phoenix/priv/static/phoenix.js +9ms   brunch:list
>   Compiled js/socket.js +2ms   brunch:file Init file
>   node_modules/phoenix/priv/static/phoenix.js +1ms   brunch:list
>   Compiled node_modules/phoenix/priv/static/phoenix.js +63ms
>   brunch:list Reading
>   node_modules/phoenix_html/priv/static/phoenix_html.js +8ms
>   brunch:list Reading ../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js
>   **> +0ms   brunch:list Reading components/my-app.vue +0ms   brunch:list Compiled js/app.js +1ms   brunch:file Init file**
>   node_modules/phoenix_html/priv/static/phoenix_html.js +0ms
>   **> brunch:file Init file components/my-app.vue +2ms   brunch:list**
>   **> Compiled components/my-app.vue +0ms   brunch:file Init file**
>   ../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js +1ms   brunch:list
>   Compiled node_modules/phoenix_html/priv/static/phoenix_html.js +6ms
>   brunch:list Reading node_modules/process/browser.js +98ms
>   brunch:list Compiled ../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js
>   +20ms   brunch:file Init file node_modules/process/browser.js +0ms   brunch:list Compiled node_modules/process/browser.js +9ms
>   brunch:write Writing 2/2 files +75ms   brunch:generate Concatenating
>   [../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js,
>   node_modules/phoenix/priv/static/phoenix.js,
>   node_modules/phoenix_html/priv/static/phoenix_html.js,
>   node_modules/process/browser.js, js/app.js, js/socket.js] =>
>   ../priv/static/js/app.js +4ms   brunch:generate Concatenating
>   [css/app.css, css/phoenix.css] => ../priv/static/css/app.css +40ms
>   brunch:generate Writing ../priv/static/js/app.js +4ms
>   brunch:generate Writing ../priv/static/js/app.js.map +7ms
>   brunch:generate Writing ../priv/static/css/app.css +1ms
>   brunch:generate Writing ../priv/static/css/app.css.map +0ms
>   brunch:write Writing 3/3 assets, removing 0 +62ms   brunch:generate
>   Writing ../priv/static/favicon.ico +0ms   brunch:generate Writing
>   ../priv/static/robots.txt +1ms   brunch:generate Writing
>   ../priv/static/images/phoenix.png +2ms 15:04:33 - info: compiled 8
>   files into 2 files, copied 3 in 2.1 sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your `brunch-config.js` is in the `assets` folder, this means that the `priv` folder is one level above the config file. Change the vue configuration to the following:

```
vue: {
  extractCSS: true,
  out: "../priv/static/css/components.css"
}
```

Comment: Both priv & assets are now top level folders in Phoenix 1.3.  I tried your solution & a full path to components.css.  Still not working?

Comment: Can you run `brunch build --debug` from the assets folder? This should show us where brunch is placing the files.

Comment: I added the brunch build --debug output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem when there was a mismatch between vue and vue-template-compiler package versions.

So check the actual versions of vue and vue-template-compiler in your package-lock.json/yarn.lock or see if you're getting an error in phoenix similar to:

```
17:04:44 - warn: Loading of vue-brunch failed due to

Vue packages version mismatch:

- vue@2.6.10
- vue-template-compiler@2.5.21
```